# How to turn a ruby hash so that the value becomes a key that points to a group of old keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
t={"4nM"=>"Triangle", "I40"=>"Triangle", "123"=>"Square"}
```

And I want to turn it into a hash like:

```
{"Triangle" => ["4nM", "I40"], "Square" => ["123"]}
```

What is the best way to do this?

I start with `group_by` but then the code gets to be a bit convoluted....

This is what I did:

```
t.group_by { |k, v| v }.map { |type, group| {type => group.flatten.reject { |x| x == type } } }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
h = { "4nM"=>"Triangle", "I40"=>"Triangle", "123"=>"Square" }

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
  #=> {"Triangle"=>["4nM", "I40"], "Square"=>["123"]}
```

The expression

```
(h[v] ||= []) << k
```

expands to

```
(h[v] = h[v] || []) << k
```

If `h` has a key `v`, `h[k]` will be truthy, so the expression above reduces to

```
(h[v] = h[v]) << k
```

and then

```
h[v] << k
```

If `h` does not have a key `v`, `h[k] #=> nil`, so the expression above reduces to

```
(h[v] = []) << k
```

resulting in

```
h[v] #=> [k]
```

Alternatively, we could write

```
h.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(k,v),h| h[v] << k }
  #=> {"Triangle"=>["4nM", "I40"], "Square"=>["123"]}
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for an explanation of the use of a block for returning the default values of keys that are not present in the hash.

Comment: I really like this... `(h[v] ||= []) << k` nice solution to a common condition

Comment: Even shorter : `t.each_with_object(Hash.new{[]}){|(k,v),h| h[v]<<= k }`

Comment: @Eric, I took a double-take when I saw `<<=`. I don't recall seeing that before. It's quite cool.

Comment: All credits go to @steenslag's answer. I've never seen it before. It's also the first time I see `Hash.new{[]}` used in anything.

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest I could write :

```
t.group_by(&:last).map{|k,v|[k,v.map(&:first)]}.to_h
```

Still 4 characters longer than @Cary Swoveland's answer.

Note that in Rails, [`Hash#transform_values`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) makes it a bit easier :

```
t.group_by{|_,v| v }.transform_values{|v| v.map(&:first) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cut it down a little bit by doing this

```
t.group_by {|k,v| v}.map{|k,v| {k => v.map(&:first)}}
```

but your original implementation was already pretty concise.

Comment: You're returning an Array of one-element Hashes.

Comment: Also you can do `.group_by(&:last)` to save one more keystroke :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `t.group_by{|k,v|v}` is also a valid syntax, and just the same length as `t.group_by(&:last)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, but if you omit the space, it becomes too terse (to my taste). :)

Comment: Sure, but if you want readable code, using last to get the value isn't the best method either ;).

Comment: @EricDuminil: I fully agree!

Answer (score 1):

```
t={"4nM"=>"Triangle", "I40"=>"Triangle", "123"=>"Square"}
h = Hash.new{[]}
t.each{|k,v| h[v] <<= k}
```

Comment: Please do not post bare code as an answer. Add some comentary on what the code is doing.

Comment: Very nice, and clever use of ` <<=`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) (Note: I'm not familiar with this domain, so this answer may actually be simple enough to make an explanation, and thus downvotes, unnecessary. You may still want to add an explanation to prevent more NAA/VLQ flags.)

Comment: @Jonathan Mee : it's basically a shorter version of Cary Swoveland's answer.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not denying the elegance of simple code. I'm just saying, as Scott Weldon has more eloquently stated, that this does not meet the answer standards set forward by http://www.stackoverflow.com